# Global error handling: HttpInterceptor vs extended class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, error-handling

In an Angular application, our standard way of catching and displaying errors is done by extending a `myErrorService` class on each component that needs it. When our component makes an HTTP request, it uses a method on `myErrorService` via `.pipe(this.myErrorServicesErrorHandlingMethod())`.

Would it be more performant and architecturally sound to instead utilize an `HttpInterceptor` (error interceptor) to handle/display all errors? It seems like there would be less code and smaller components, since we wouldn't have to extend multiple components and could instead automatically intercept our HTTP calls, but I don't know much about the performance of HttpInterceptor.

Comment: Performance is not a problem. `HttpInterceptor` is just as fast, if not faster, than an extra `pipe()` on every http request. But still, the performance impact is absolutely negligible - what you should care about is a clean architecture, and duplicating code across all http-using services and forcing a specific inheritance hierarchy smells.

Comment: Agreed with @Bergi. This is what interceptors are for. Also, in your example, inheritance seems completely overkill anyway? You can simply import that operator without extending a base class for it?